# ListFragments crashing the program

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I was trying to implement lisadapter in a fragment, but Java does not allow to extend two superclasses. Thus I was not able to extend Fragment and ListActivity to the same class. Then I changed my app. I replaced all fragments with ListFragment. But When I run my application, it crashes. Earlier it was running fine. Could you pleasa help me out .
Please find below the logcat entries

I have pasted the protab1.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
             >


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(959): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pro1/com.example.pro1.Secactivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(959): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
E/AndroidRuntime(959):  ... 11 more
```

Activity class holding ListFragments protab1 and protab2

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Secactivity extends Activity {
    public static Context mycontext ;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.promain);
        mycontext = getApplicationContext();

        //ActionBar
            ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
            actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            ActionBar.Tab PlayerTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
            ActionBar.Tab StationsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment B");

            ListFragment PlayerFragment = new Protab1();
            ListFragment StationsFragment = new Protab2();

            PlayerTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(PlayerFragment));
            StationsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(StationsFragment));

            actionbar.addTab(PlayerTab);
            actionbar.addTab(StationsTab);
        }


}

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public ListFragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(ListFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(Secactivity.mycontext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

}
```

protab1 ListFragment

```
package com.example.pro1;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Protab1 extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.protab1, container, false);
    }



}
```

protab2 ListFragment

```
package com.example.pro1;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Protab2 extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.protab2, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats is the exception,see it in the logcat and paste it here

Comment: could you paste the logcat as well

Comment: Please paste your protab1.xml, according to logcat there is error in it.

Comment: Hi Lawrence, I have pasted the xml for protab1 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line and let me know if it doesn't work:
(from Activity to FragmentActivity)

```
public class Secactivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Comment: Hi Sanotsh, I changed it but still the app is crashing.

Comment: then as i have mentioned above in the comment, paste the logcat. Also, whenever you get a working solution from someone, try to mark it as answer.

Comment: Hi Santosh, I hve pasted the logcat in the question itself. Sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: I think The problem is in your layout file. check the listview id in layout files protab1 and protab2.

Answer (score 0):

Add this include to your list layout:

```
<include layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

This worked for me....

Documentation on android site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

> public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup
>   container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
>
> Added in API level 11 Provide default implementation to return a
>   simple list view. Subclasses can override to replace with their own
>   layout. If doing so, **the returned view hierarchy must have a ListView
>   whose id is android.R.id.list** and can optionally have a sibling view
>   id android.R.id.empty that is to be shown when the list is empty.
>
> ***If you are overriding this method with your own custom content,
>   consider including the standard layout list_content in your layout***
>   file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard behavior of
>   ListFragment. In particular, this is currently the only way to have
>   the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.